# How to INSERT INTO with SELECT statement for columns with FOREIGN KEY in Node.js with mysql package

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, node-mysql

I'm trying to INSERT INTO my table idea a new record based on values I'm getting from POST. The tricky part is that I need to fill a foreign key id bases on my value name. My values are valid I'm sure, the problem is the statement.

This is for a Node.js app working with mysql package from NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql).

My columns are idea.name, idea.short_description, idea.description, idea.difficulty and category_id.

The statement I want to do is "INSERT INTO idea SET name = '', short_description = '', description = '', difficulty = '', category_id = (SELECT id FROM category WHERE name = '')"

The select part is the problem because I tried to attach a default number (1) and it's working.

I have to deal with mysql package that is:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO idea SET name = ?, short_description = ?, description = ?, difficulty = ?, category_id = 1', [name, short_description, description, difficulty, category_id], (err, result) => {
if (err) throw err
cb(result)
})
```

I would like something looking like this:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO idea SET name = ?, short_description = ?, description = ?, difficulty = ?, category = (SELECT id FROM category WHERE name = ' + category ')', [name, short_description, description, difficulty, category], (err, result) => {
if (err) throw err
cb(result)
})
```

I expect to get my foreign key id thanks to my foreign key name. So I try to find category.id with category.name.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your problem is that you want to ran a sub-query when doing the `INSERT`. This is what I'm seeing in your code:

```sql
INSERT INTO idea
SET name = ?
  , short_description = ?
  , description = ?
  , difficulty = ?
  , category = (
      SELECT id
      FROM category
      WHERE name = ?
    )
```

So then why don't split the `INSERT+SELECT` as a two-steps procedure, first `SELECT` and then `INSERT`

Using this approach you would need two queries:

1. `SELECT`

```sql
SELECT id
FROM category
WHERE name = ?
```

2. `INSERT`

```sql
INSERT INTO idea
SET name = ?
  , short_description = ?
  , description = ?
  , difficulty = ?
  , category = ?
```

Also a nice side-effect is that you have a place to decide what happens when the category id is not found.

Comment: I agree with this approach, split the SQL commands responsibility normally is the best thing to do. But, why do you not use some orm like sequelize or knex? They really help us.